# Is it possible in Java to modify certain line of the text file, without over-writing everything

Tags: java, file-io

I have a text file. I want to modify only one line somewhere inside that file. I don't want to over-write other lines of the file (which is extremely slow, on large files).

I'm not refering to *append mode* where I can "add" lines at the end; but rather, "edit".

Comment: This is not really a Java issue, but more of a physical issue of how files are stored on a computer as sequential bits of data.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a RandomAccessFile. You change change the contents of the first line.

What you cannot do is insert or delete any bytes as this requires you to shift all the data from the point you do this. (If this is close to the end of the file it can be much faster than re-writing everything)

Also RandomAccessFile is difficult to use with `char` as it designed for use with `byte`s

Answer (score 2):

Your title states "certain line" - your question body states "the first line". Modifying the first line is *much* simpler, as you don't need to find the starting byte of the line. You can use [`RandomAccessFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) to overwrite the relevant chunk of the file.

However, the new line will have to be the same size (in bytes) as the old line. If the useful data in the new line is shorter than in the old line, you'll need to work out how to pad it. If the new line needs to be *longer* than the old line, you'll have to create a new file instead, copying the data appropriately.

Generally, file systems don't support insertion or deletion within an existing file.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this (this is by no way an optimal code).

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test {
    // provide the file name via the command line
    public static void main(String []args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("your_file_name_here")); // used for reading the file
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("new_file_name_here.txt"));
        String str = br.readLine();
        while (str != null) {
            // modify the line here if you want, otherwise it will written as is.
            // then write it using the BufferedWriter
            bw.write(str, 0, str.length());
            bw.newLine();
            // read the next line
            str = br.readLine();
        }
        br.close();
        bw.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: So its like copying contents from one file to another

Comment: you can put like that or if you want you can use the RandomAccessFile class to access certain bytes and convert them to a string, modify the string, convert it back to bytes and then write it to the old file. but that requires some work. as i said the code above is by no means an optimal one.